# ASP.NET: How do I re-route /favicon.ico to a FaviconController without using the <link> tag?

Tags: asp.net, routes, favicon

I am currently using a  tag to display a custom favicon file depending on user configuration using a FaviconController ActionResult.

However, when a PDF file is served to Chrome, Chrome will still use the root /favicon.ico as the tab icon, meaning that when the user download/views a PDF, they get the static favicon.ico that I have in the root folder.  This results in an inconsistent user experience (==bad).

In ASP.NET, how do I modify the route to the static /favicon.ico so that the request is ALWAYS served by the FaviconController?

Answer (score 1):

You should place this code in your routeconfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "favicon.ico",
    url: "favicon.ico",
    defaults: new { controller = "Favicon", action = "<Some custom action there>" }
);
```

Comment: I tried this, using "Index" as the action, but the controller action is not hit. Ctrl+Shift+R in Chrome with localhost:51350/favicon.ico in the URL bar does not hit the action either.

Comment: I think it works not on on all IIS versions. You could also try to use PreBeginRequest to catch requests to favicon.ico and rewrite them.